# how can i get ID in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, sfguard, symfony-1.4

I was creating its own login system, but all recommmended sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. unfortunately I dont understand this...

I go to **http://localhost/frontend_dev.php/login** and i logged in. i am in **class sfGuardSecurityUser** and method **public function signIn($user, $remember = false, $con = null)**
where there did variable $user?

there is:

```
$this->setAttribute('user_id', $user->getId(), 'sfGuardSecurityUser');
```

but if i use:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('user_id');
```

in own module then it is NULL. Works only $this->getUser(); but this is only Name and login. How can i get ID logged user?

I also added in table **sf_guard_user_permission** user_id 2 permission_id 2 and how can i check this in other module?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple, in an action for exemple :
    $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();